# WebApplication on a Different Server

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis, webserver

I have a web based mobile application(asp.net) working on a server . If I want to make the same application run on a different server. What steps do I need to take? So far I have found that , I need to have a domain name and the Web server to host the application. There is IIS installed on the other server. Can it be used to host the web application on the internet. 
Some of the questions may sound stupid. I apologize for that. I am a novice at this.. Any help would be appreciated . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The particular steps depend on the current server you are working with. However, to answer your question about IIS, you can definitely host a web app there. On the server with IIS "C:\inetpub\wwwroot" is usually the default physical path to store web apps, so you could put a copy there. Here's a quick help doc for IIS 7:

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772042(v=ws.10).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772042%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I copied all the files and stored it under innetpub/wwwroot and added the folder to the Default Web Sites inside the IIS sites section. However this procedure didn't work .Does anybody know why ? Any alternatives to it ?

Comment: @user3608997 I do not know what "doesn't work" means. You need to describe what you tried to do and what the issue is.

Comment: I apologize for that 
1) Copied all the files related to the web app into the new server i.e(inetpub/wwwroot)
2) Created a new web site in the Sites part of the IIS manager and tried to open the file in IE, but the page was blank without any error.

Comment: I don't think you want a new website in IIS, you can use the Default Web Site (in IIS Manager left panel, "serverName --> Sites --> Default Web Site"). In wwwroot make a new folder for the app where you copy the files (.../wwwroot/myApp), and then in IIS under the Default Web Site if you expand down, does your folder that you copied files into show-up?